# Class method vs having an instance "Manager"

Tags: python

Suppose I have a class such as the following:

```
class MyItem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.person = None
        self.place = None            
        self.thing = None
```

And I want to do things to "groups of" these objects, for example, "Get items that are in place=DE, "Update all persons with a name with a non-ASCI character", and so forth.

For doing something like this, what are the benefits of doing something like:

```
MyItem.run_class_method()
```

Or having an entirely separate class that acts as the "Manager", something like:

```
MyItemManager...(lots of methods)
```

Are there suggested ways on how to structure classes similar to how a database might work with "objects" or rows (row=instance, and various "methods" to do various things with groups of the data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefered way, and it's mandatory if you have a "lot" of methods, is to create a separated item manager class.

Here are some advantages :

- Item don't need to know about item manager to be instantiated
- Class will be more clear
- If you add a lot of modification in one class, that should not affect the others
- Easy to maintain